# Dynamic search in ADF

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf, webcenter

I have a search page with multiple search options(input text boxes) Based on the search criteria entered , I need to create a dynamic search query. (I need search results based on the fields for which user inputs some value)

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `<af:quickQuery>` for a simple search. Here's the sample code taken from Oracle [demo](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/quickQuery.jspx).

```
<af:quickQuery label="Search" id="search" searchDesc="search" binding="#{editor.component}" value="#{demoQuickQuery.queryDescriptor}" queryListener="#{demoQuickQuery.processQuery}">

</af:quickQuery>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADF/BC, this is built-in. Just use the [`<af:query/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_query.html) component.

Answer (score 0):

[af:query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_query.html) is the more robust of the two query components, but does require you create a [viewcriteria](http://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/whats_the_difference_between_view_criteria_and_where_clause) object in the VO that will be the basis for the query. However it is very powerful: dynamically add new attributes to the query at runtime, change query rules (starts with, contains, etc)

[af:quickquery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_quickQuery.html) allows you to choose one and only one attribute to query on at a time.

Please note: these components (and the executewithparms) are the *only* supported query methods in ADF Faces 11g